# Ordering Postgresql query result on Housenumber column by custom comparer

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using **postgresql** as DB.
Using my query to select column housenumber of varchar type(and some other columns) from table with buildings info. So I want the result to be ordered other way, rather then string comparison.

For example, if I have following results:

```
"1"
"1 block2"
"1 b30"
"1 b3"
"1 b3 s4"
"10"
"2"
```

I want this result to be sorted by following logic:

1. 1) getting source string `"1 b3 s4"`
2. 2) split it into `["1" , "b3" , "s4"]`
3. 3) try to parse all substrings to integer, ignoring letters, which
   are not numbers into `[1 , 3, 4]`
4. 4) calculate bigger number for future sorting as

   ```
   1 * 1000000 + 3 * 1000 + 4 = 1003004.
   ```

Is this possible and how could I implement this methoad and use it for sorting query result?

Here is my sql query(shorted):

```
SELECT housenumber, name
FROM osm_buildings
where
    housenumber <> ''      
order by housenumber
limit 100
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to convert to some big integer for sorting.  You can do the following:

- Remove all characters that are not digits or spaces.
- Convert to an array, splitting on one or more spaces.
- Convert the array to an integer array.

Then you can can sort on this:

```
order by regexp_split_to_array(regexp_replace(v.addr, '[^0-9 ]', '', 'g'), ' +')::int[]
```

You can store this as a value in a table, if you want to persist it.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=77752731e5a2cc7415a7c8305e55e771) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Trying it now, looks like it should work. But on my DB it throws exception like wrong value for "". Feels like ' where housenumber <> '' ' is not applied before ordering.

Comment: I found out solution. 'regexp_replace(..)' should be wrapped with trim()